# How old is the phrase "A Healthy Pee" (or "A Healthy Piss")

Tags: etymology, phrases, history

What is the earliest usage of the phrase "a healthy pee" or "a healthy piss"?

The letter "P", or its spelled form, "pee", used euphemistically for "piss" (because "piss" begins with that letter -- as, similarly, in modern times, sometimes we hear one say "Go F yourself"), seems to be poorly dated. But when did people start applying the adjective "healthy" to any act of urination?

Answer (score 1):

*Healthy* has meant "in quantity" for a while.

From [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/healthy)

> 4b : not small or feeble : considerable

I don't know if "healthy piss" has anything to do with copious urination as a sign or cause of actual good health.